# Icon in png for bottom navigation bar android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, bottomnavigationview

In My Bottom navigation bar, I am using an icon in the menu XML, the icon color changed with the theme color when selected.

after the tab click the icon totally change I am totally stuck why this happens with the png image.

**Bottom navigation**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemBackground="@color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_compas"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/discover_green"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

**Bottom_nav_menu**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/chatMenuFragment"
            android:enabled="true"enter code here
            android:icon="@drawable/chat_selector"
            android:title="Chat"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contactsFragment"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/people_selector"
            android:title="People"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/discoverFragment"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/discover_selector"
            android:title="Discovery"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/myProfileFragment"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/user_selector"
            android:title="My"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    </menu>
```

**screenshots**

Before selection:

[image]

After selection:

[image]

Comment: what is your `discover_green` drawable?

Comment: I can't see yours screenshot, same with link. can you reupload it ?

Comment: before selected
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmEU.png
After
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gLo.png

Comment: Please show your disabled and enabled compass icons. I'm almost sure that white space inside the compass is white but not a transparent.

Comment: ic_compass
https://ibb.co/SnjFvWs

discover_green
https://ibb.co/ns8N58H

Comment: Ou. Thats make sense.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue, the problem is that by default the bottom navigation view adds a tint to the drawables and fills everything that is not transparent (like the case of your assets).

try adding this line
`bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = null`

Answer (score 2):

"@drawable/discover_green" check this drawble , is it what you you're getting after pressing the compass ?

you're using a state list drawable so when you press compass the icon changes to discover_green, it is same as you defined.
The solution is the completely delete the state list drawble and use just the icon or changed the green dot icon to something you want to use.

Comment: before selected
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbmEU.png
After
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gLo.png

thanku  for reply . these screenshot help u to find my problem

Comment: is there any way that icon design will not change in bottom navigation . it uses it own theme color in my icon ,thats why icon totally changed

Comment: the icon which it changes after pressing is defined by you in the xml resource it is not doing it on it own , you can simple not use state list drawble to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that selected state apply color filter for whole not transparent part of icon. To fix your selected icon you have to make arrows on green circle transparent not white. Ask designer for change it or do it in some editor by your own.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises from the fact that `discover_green.png` file has no transparent area. So when the menu item is selected the green tint is applied to the whole image hence you see a green circle.

However in `ic_compas.png` everything except the compas is transparent, Meaning if you use it as `icon` the compas in image will turn green when selected. For this you will have to modify the `Discovery menu item` as

```
       <item
        android:id="@+id/discoverFragment"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_compas"
        android:title="Discovery"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

This will give you a grey compas if item is not selected and a green compas when selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create color icon and simple icon both and at selection time you have to change icon form plain to color and on not select time you have to change color icon to plain icon this is the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the white filter on the drawable item (png or vector) with this code (but you cant colour the icons on touch):

```
bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = null
```